# ethernet not found- load module into linux kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kernel-modules

We got a new server at work and I installed harddrive from the old system. Ubuntu 8.04 boots up just fine. The only problem is:

```
$ifup eth0
device not found

$lspci
Ethernet Controller Intel Pro(100/1000)

$dmesg | grep eth
(nothing)
```

Should I add some sort of default ethernet module using `modprobe` or is there another way?

```
$cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx

$lsmod<br/>
[gist](https://gist.github.com/1004662)
```

Comment: Please copy-paste *exact* commands and errors. I'm pretty sure you didn't run `lspic`, and I don't recognize `device not found` as the sole output from `ifup eth0`. Also tell us what you have in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: The installer really should be detecting the Intel card. They aren't exactly obscure. What is the the output of `lsmod`, please? And, yes /etc/network/interfaces, unless you are using that network manager thing, in which case, paste the config file for that. And please tell us if you are using network manager.

Comment: yes we are using network manager:

Comment: sorry I can't paste with no network connection

Comment: I added lsmod output and interfaces file is there anything else I could post?

Comment: @Caleb what should I do after modprobe e1000 ? it does get added to lsmod output but is gone after reboot. thanks

Comment: @teaforthecat: Does network manager work if you modprobe `e1000`? First check that. If you want the module to be loaded at every boot you can add it to `/etc/modules`, or `/etc/modprobe.d/`. The former is more customary in this kind of situation, I think. I don't understand why the installer didn't detect your card though. I recommend you report a bug report with the installer's debugging output. For those who aren't aware, network manager doesn't use `/etc/network/interfaces`, so it isn't relevant here.

Comment: @Faheem I thought network manager used /etc/network/interfaces if you told it to using _auto_ eth0. no network manager doesn't work after modprobe e1000. I put that in /etc/modules, too. Also, I didn't run the installer; I just put the hard drive into the new machine.

Comment: @teaforthecat: I don't know anything about network installer, except that (I thought) it ignored `/etc/network/interfaces`. So you may be right. Ok, switching your hard drives between machines is unlikely to be a successful installation technique. I suggest you reinstall your root partition, assuming you have your other (data) partitions separate. I also prefer using /etc/network/interfaces because that is the traditional Debian way, and is more transparent imo. but, ymmv.

Comment: @Faheem I agree it is not correct technique,but it worked on another machine, and it is so close. oh well. Should I try to upgrade from a live usb? or what would be the best technique recompile kernel? thank you

Comment: @teaforthecat: if you really don't want to reinstall, and the network is the only thing not wokring, then you could try using `/etc/network/interfaces`. That may be easier to debug than network manager. Does `lsmod` show `e1000` on reboot, if it is in `/etc/modules`? Also, did you verify that `e1000` is the correct module for your card? For the record, the installer does a bunch of configuration, eg with `udev`, which in general you don't really want to reproduce manually. An installation should be considered to be tied to  a machine, unless you are moving to a *very* similar machine.

Comment: @teaforthecat: if you go this route, you'll also want to modify the udev net rule. On my machine (Debian squeeze) it is at `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. Yours is probably similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `modprobe e1000` or `modprobe e1000e`.

Answer (score 1):

this solved the issue:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=3370406
(recompiling the module)

sorry it wasn't more clear that the hard drive was taken from another machine

Answer (score 0):

### Generic Linux Recovery steps for "My Internet Ethernet won't connect":

1. Re-Confirm that your internet and wired Cat5 cable is available and working correctly by plugging the Cat5 into another computer and connecting. If that just works, then internet and the Cat5 cable is good. Otherwise replace those.
2. Re-Confirm that there aren't any superfluous, bugged or lightning-struck devices or set top boxes between your computer and the ISP service provider, such as 5 port hubs, switches, routers (bridge mode or otherwise) or other relay devices. By eliminating these network hops, you confirm that your computer can hit the default gateway and dhcp configure itself.  If that fixes, flash-update hub/switch/router's hardware, or replace.
3. If it's a new computer, Re-Confirm that your computer has the BIOS/CMOS or motherboard settings enabled for Ethernet card, your computer might have support for multiple Ethernet cards, or you're simply plugging into the non-default one. Press F2/F12/Del after reboot and find any settings in regards to Ethernet, or network stack, enable/disable legacy IPv4 and IPv6 settings.
4. Boot to a liveCD.  Get the image.iso or download the Bootable USB stick from the official boot media website like Ubuntu, Arch, SystemRescueCD or similar.
   Motherboard/Ethernet Manufacturers, especially weird 3rd parties, introduce breaking updates to TCP/IP, and Linux developers have to fix it with software updates.
5. Re-Confirm that your computer isn't getting hung up negotiating between two or more Ethernet cards which may be bugged. If you can remove a removable Ethernet card, that may isolate. Your Ethernet card might be knockoff 3rd party, use modprobe to load the ethernet driver your manufacturer endorses.
6. Now the integrity of your Ethernet hardware or boot media reader is suspect. Try a different LiveCD or different Boot USB.  Burn that to CD or Boot USB. If that one just works, it proves at least your Ethernet and motherboard hardware is good and hasn't given up the ghost.
7. If Ethernet still doesn't autoconnect from any of these boot mediums. The Hardware is suspect. Remove any unnecessary PCI cards that can be removed, remove unnecessary Memory.
8. If god forbid none of that works, perhaps Linux is getting behind the 8 ball, try installing a different kind of operating system.
9. If none of that works, your hardware has given up the ghost. If it's under Warranty open a service ticket for tech help and or replacement parts, if that fails, ship it back to the manufacturer.  If that fails, throw it into the trash and get a nicer profession, like gardening.

Comment: You've missed the part where Caleb identified the problem with a simple `modprobe` command to load the pertinent module.

Comment: Understood, but the 9 thousand people who landed on this page did so because they typed a query into google, like: "Ethernet Controller Intel Pro Ethernet device not found".    And so modprobe is very unlikely to be the answer to their problem.  Check my 130k reputation on my other accounts and watch as this becomes the most upvoted answer over the next year or so, as people land here, and say aha, that's my problem.  And submit their upboat.

Comment: Then I would suggest softening your wording around "perhaps Linux is getting behind the 8 ball, try installing a different kind of operating system." when posting on a site named UNIX & Linux :)